android studio api 34 update google play app
There is a mobile application developed with Flutter. I changed the sdk targets in the build.gradle file and the application version code in the pubspec.yaml file without updating the Flutter version.
The application can now be downloaded in its new form (sdk 34), but the Google Play Console did not remove the update structure warning for API 34. What should I do?
Screenshot in code;


Could you please clarify what kind of update structure warning is still being flagged by Google Play Console? If you’ve updated the target SDK to 34 and released the new app on the Play Console without any breaking changes, you shouldn't need to worry about the warnings
